# Displaying a circular image through UIimageview and uiimagepicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

New to Swift and can't manage to find the most conclusive way to alter my code for it to enable to crop an image upon selection from the users library and reveal itself on an image view as a complete circular image.

Furthermore, how do i present and image cropper like https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper in an swift project?

Here is the code i have been trying out:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let imagePicked = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.5
    let cornerRadius:CGFloat = imageView.frame.height/2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
imageView.clipsToBounds = true


    // Create a multiplier to scale up the corner radius and border

    // width you decided on relative to the imageViewer frame such



    // that the corner radius and border width can be converted to

    // the UIImage's scale.


    let multiplier:CGFloat = imagePicked.size.height/imageView.frame.size.height > imagePicked.size.width/imageView.frame.size.width ?


        imagePicked.size.height/imageView.frame.size.height :
        imagePicked.size.width/imageView.frame.size.width

    let borderWidthMultiplied:CGFloat = borderWidth * multiplier

    let cornerRadiusMultiplied:CGFloat = cornerRadius * multiplier


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imagePicked.size, false, 0)

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectInset(CGRectMake(50, 50, imagePicked.size.width, imagePicked.size.height),

        borderWidthMultiplied / 2, borderWidthMultiplied / 2), cornerRadius: cornerRadiusMultiplied)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    // Clip the drawing area to the path
    path.addClip()



    // Draw the image into the context
    imagePicked.drawInRect(CGRectMake(50, 50, imagePicked.size.width, imagePicked.size.height))
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)



    // Configure the stroke
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = borderWidthMultiplied



    // Stroke the border
    path.stroke()
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    print("picker cancel.")
}
```

Comment: Set image View width and height same. And set corner radius for imageView is (width/2).

Comment: Thanks this worked great

Comment: @Vineesh check it out bro and this one to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981392/displaying-data-on-a-tableview-calling-contacts-from-a-picker-to-tableview-29-a

Comment: @A dot: If my answer is correct please accept the my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Image To be Circular your imageView should be square....First get image from UIimagepicker and set this image to UIimageview which should be square (Equal Width and height) and 
UIimageview *imageView = CGRectMake(x-axis,y-axis,side,side);

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = side/2;
imageView.clipToBounds = YES;
```

set the corner radius of UIimageview to half the height of side of square
Secondly, you have to set the clipsToBounds property to YES in order to make the layer works.

Comment: Right let me post whats up now

Comment: @Vineesh So i managed to get it round but the image is an oval instead of a perfect circle guys

Comment: What is Ppic? Is it imageView? If it is imageView then what is frame of that view??

Comment: Ppic = imagView yeah

Answer (score 0):

Set image View **width and height should be same** and set corner radius for imageView is (width/2)

Example:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Oval imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxyCC.png)As you can see from the photo i got it to display a circle thanks to Vineesh and Himan. That being said, the image view displays an oval like image and not a full circle. Any thoughts guys?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    //handle media here i.e. do stuff with photo


    Ppic.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    Ppic.layer.masksToBounds = false
    Ppic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    Ppic.layer.cornerRadius = 13
  Ppic.layer.cornerRadius = Ppic.frame.size.height/2
   Ppic.clipsToBounds = true



    print("imagePickerController called")

    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    Ppic.image = chosenImage
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    //what happens when you cancel
    //which, in our case, is just to get rid of the photo picker which pops up
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: @Himan Ppic is the Image view:            

 Ppic.layer.cornerRadius = Ppic.frame.size.height/2