# Displaying data on a tableView: Calling contacts from a picker to tableView 29 and counting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contacts, picker

Aaanyway, I wanted to ask if its possible to populate a table view from my contacts picker. I'm using this library: https://github.com/ipraba/EPContactsPicker

This is my picker:

```
///CONTACTS PICKER\\\

@IBAction func onTouchShowMeContactsButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let contactPickerScene = EPContactsPicker(delegate: self, multiSelection:true, subtitleCellType: SubtitleCellValue.Email)
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactPickerScene)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//MARK: EPContactsPicker delegates
func epContactPicker(_: EPContactsPicker, didContactFetchFailed error : NSError)
{
    print("Failed with error \(error.description)")
}

func epContactPicker(_: EPContactsPicker, didSelectContact contact : EPContact)
{
    print("Contact \(contact.displayName()) has been selected")
}

func epContactPicker(_: EPContactsPicker, didCancel error : NSError)
{
    print("User canceled the selection");
}

func epContactPicker(_: EPContactsPicker, didSelectMultipleContacts contacts: [EPContact]) {
    print("The following contacts are selected")
    for contact in contacts {
        print("\(contact.displayName())")
    }
```

After I select the contacts I want to be able to show them on the table view like this:  [TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRl9.png)

If there is no answer or if You guys think I don't deserve the help due to my lack of experience, please send me the aid through tutorials of some sort or any relatable information of some sort. 
Thank y'all for the time and effort. <3

Answer (score 0):

To get the contact details from phone you can use the apple library, `ABAddressBookRef`

[Please check the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html)

Comment: I shall check out and report back to this Thanks bud